# Caused by java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2 by SoftKeyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-softkeyboard

Hey I am working to detect the custom keyboard in my application. I did this successfully and detect user is custom keyboard by using code

```
fun isUsingCustomKeyboard(context: Context): Boolean {
        val imm: InputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        val inputMethodProperties: List<InputMethodInfo> = imm.enabledInputMethodList
        for (i in 0..inputMethodProperties.size) { // loop to every input method
            val inputMethodInfo = inputMethodProperties[i]
            val inputMethodId = Settings.Secure.getString(
                context.contentResolver,
                Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD
            )
            if (inputMethodInfo.id.equals(inputMethodId)) {
                if (inputMethodInfo.serviceInfo.applicationInfo.flags and ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM == 0) {
                    return true
                }
                break
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

But I am getting this error, can someone suggest me what's going wrong in my above code

```
com.example.android.KeyboardHelper.isUsingCustomKeyboard (KeyboardHelper.kt:15)
com.example.android.trackKeyboardType (SignInActivity.kt:75)
com.example.android.onCreate (SignInActivity.kt:71)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8207)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:8191)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1309)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3808)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:4011)
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2325)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8633)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for (i in 0..inputMethodProperties.size) {` size gives number of objects in list but index starts at 0 so when you try read the last its out of bounds. size -1 is the last index.

Comment: `(i in 0..inputMethodProperties.size-1)` like that i need to use?

Comment: you could change it to `for (inputMethodInfo in inputMethodProperties) {` and remove the line `val inputMethodInfo = inputMethodProperties[i]`